# Grails Mail Plugin doesnt install - try to fix in Config but still doesnt work

Tags: grails, groovy, communication

I need to install the mail plugin for grails. The console shows the following error:

```
Failed to install plugin [mail-1.0-SNAPSHOT]. Plugin has missing JAR dependencies.
```

I tryed to fix some things in the buildconfig.groovy according to guides to this problem I googled, but it keeps showing this error message above.
Things I inserted into the buildconfig.groovy

```
dependencies {

    compile "javax.mail:mail:1.4.3"
    runtime "org.springframework:org.springframework.test:3.0.3.RELEASE"

    runtime( ':mail:1.0-SNAPSHOT' ) {
    excludes "spring-test"}


}
```

the plugin doesnt install (I tried to install it from the "run target" console. Can somebody help pleas?
thanks a lot,
Daniel

Comment: How exactly did you try to install the plugin? Did you used the [common approach](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-plugin.html)? PS: I would have answered as a comment, but I don't have the reputation right now, my only choice is to give a complete answer.

Comment: I installed it via 2 ways: in "run target", typing 'install-plugin mail', and via tools -> grails -> plugins -> mail

Comment: Which grails version do you use?
You already found [this bug report](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPMAIL-14)?

Comment: I use grails 1.3.7. I know this bug report. The link in it shows what I did in my code in my question post.

Comment: in general I want to send Email from my application, I thought the mail plugin is comfortable

Answer (score 1):

Can you trying installing version 0.9 ? I know that works for us.

Comment: I will try this. Is there a documentation for 0.9 still online? or does the configuration work like with 1.0 SNAPSHOT? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a shoot from the hip: is mavenCentral() uncommented in the repositories section?

Comment: it is commentented/not executed, should I uncomment it?

Comment: I uncommented it, and it did more than before when trying to install mail. But it's still not properly installed. I tryed to install it a second time after uncommented mavenCentral(), and then it stopped at the "Cant resolve JAR dependencies" again.