# Must issue a STARTTLS command first when trying to send a SimpleMailMessage in Grails

Tags: java, email, grails, communication

I try to send a message in a grails application. I use Java code with this problem tho, here is my code

```
SimpleMailMessage message_ref = new SimpleMailMessage();
JavaMailSenderImpl sender_ref = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

           sender_ref.setHost("smtp.gmail.com")
           sender_ref.setUsername("testAccount@googlemail.com")
           sender_ref.setPassword("topsecret")
           message_ref.setTo("testRecipient@gmx.de")
           message_ref.setSubject("Hello there")
           message_ref.setText("How are you")
           sender_ref.send(message_ref)
```

I'm getting the following exception:

> SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

I found a similar problem here on stackoverflow here
[Must issue a STARTTLS command first. Sending email with Java and Google Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386083/must-issue-a-starttls-command-first-sending-email-with-java-and-google-apps)
but it didn't help me cause he used an different approach.

Can somebody tell me what's wrong? I'm expecting the error is not in the code but in some configuration file and this is where my knowledge edges.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the [Grails mail plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/mail) docs:

```
grails {
   mail {
     host = "smtp.gmail.com"
     port = 465
     username = "youracount@gmail.com"
     password = "yourpassword"
     props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",                     
              "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
              "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
              "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
} }
```

Comment: Thank you, but the Mails Plug in doesnt work with my project, I try to fix it in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692543/grails-mail-plugin-doesnt-install-try-to-fix-in-config-but-still-doesnt-work , but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you much, but your problem is basically that you need to use SSL to communicate with the server. Google does not allow plain-text communication for a lot of good reasons. I don't know much about grails, but I assume it has some sort of ssl-support. If it does not, you're probably better off doing it in javax.mail.

StartTLS is just a text-command you send to the smtp-server to explicitly start secure communications.

Comment: ok that helped a bit, then Ill try with Javax Mail. Does this APi include "Mimemessage" and its helper classes?

Comment: I implemented it with javax.mail classes and this error message shows again

Answer (score 0):

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort);
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.put("mail.user", userName);
properties.put("mail.password", password);
```

Comment: the problems is often cause by not adding properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); as part of the properties

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation would help current and future users understand your answer even better.